# 400 Error in People API [people.updateContact ]

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

400 Error in People API [people.updateContact]

I'm need updateContact field locations of user in g-suite

i get 400 error "Resource name "people/{xxxxxxx}" is not a valid contact person resource."

> request

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "etag": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "locations": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "PROFILE",
          "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
      },
      "value": "TestA",
      "current": true
    },
    {
      "metadata": {
        "source": {
          "type": "PROFILE",
          "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
      },
      "value": "TestB"
    }
  ]
}
```

> response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Resource name \"people/{xxxxxxx}\" is not a valid contact person resource.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*The error `"Resource name \"people/{xxxxxxx}\" is not a valid contact person resource."` appears because the resource name you are providing in your request is not a valid contact person resource.*

#### Fix:

Replace `people/{xxxxxxx}` with  a valid resource. You can obtain these using [people.listDirectoryPeople](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/listDirectoryPeople) endpoint.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP was just sanitizing his output for public consumption.  I have the same issue trying to delete a shared contact and I am submitting a valid resourceName.